# How Do I match two Data Frames in Pandas with multiple matches?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames I want to match some data from one data frame and append it on another.

df1 looks like this:

| sourceId | firstName | lastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | John | Doe |
| 5678 | Sally | Green |
| 9101 | Chlodovech | Anderson |

df2 looks like this:

| sourceId | agentId |
| --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 1234,5678 |
| 987654321 | 9101 |
| 143216546 | 1234,5678 |

I want my Final Data Frame to look like this:

| sourceId | firstName | lastName | agentId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | John | Doe | 123456789,143216546 |
| 5678 | Sally | Green | 123456789,143216546 |
| 9101 | Chlodovech | Anderson | 987654321 |

Usually appending stuff is easy but I'm not quite sure how to match this data up, and then append the matches with commas in-between them. I'm fairly new to using pandas so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. It's long and not the most elegant, but it works well :)

```
tmp = df2.assign(agentId=df2['agentId'].str.split(',')).explode('agentId').set_index('agentId')['sourceId'].astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg(list).str.join(',').reset_index()
df1['sourceId'] = df1['sourceId'].astype(str)
new_df = df1.merge(tmp, left_on='sourceId', right_on='agentId').drop('agentId',axis=1).rename({'sourceId_x':'sourceId', 'sourceId_y':'agentId'},axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
  sourceId   firstName  lastName              agentId
0     1234        John       Doe  123456789,143216546
1     5678       Sally     Green  123456789,143216546
2     9101  Chlodovech  Anderson            987654321
```